# How to get observable property name KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
function Employee() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("John");
}

ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // implementation
    }
}

<div data-bind="test: name"></div>
```

Is there a way to get the observable name? not the value of the observable.

TIA.

Update:

This is the code snippet.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
       type: type,
       url: url,
       success: function (data) {
           ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {} , self);
       }
    });
    self.item = ko.observable(self.my_item); 
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

}

ko.bindingHandlers.item = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $el = $(element);
        var propName = allBindings().name;
        var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $el.attr("src", val);

        $el.click(function () {
            viewModel.selectedItem(propName); 
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $el = $(element);
        var ops = allBindings().name;
        var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $el.attr("src", val);
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.selectItem = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $el = $(element);
        $el.attr("src", valueAccessor());
        $el.click(function () {
            bindingContext.$data.item()[ko.unwrap(bindingContext.$data.selectedItem)](valueAccessor());
        });
    }
};


<img height="25" width="25" data-bind="item: item().img1, name: 'img1'" />
<img height="20" width="20" data-bind="selectItem: '/images/myimage1.png'" />
<img height="20" width="20" data-bind="selectItem: '/images/myimage2.png'" />
<img height="20" width="20" data-bind="selectItem: '/images/myimage3.png'" />
```

When you click images that has `selectItem` the first image should replaced its `src` attribute. If you have better way to do this please suggest.

FYI, the properties inside `items` observables are link of images.

TIA.

Comment: You don't need the observable name. Explain why you think you do and I show you why you don't.

Comment: I have to agree with @Tomalak.  This smells very much of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you _actually_ trying to solve?

Comment: I'm using the bindingContext parameter to change the viewmodels' value. so I need to get the observable name to use bindingContext.$data.myprop["my_prop2"]. my_prop2 should be dyanimic so I can manage to change the value of whatever is inside the "myprop" property. Is there other way to do that?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to put too much logic in your view / bindings, rather than dealing with it in the backend model code.

Comment: I mapped my ajax return to become my observables so I don't repeat myself too much.

Comment: I already did it by the code of super cool below. But is there any other way to do that? Like he said it's the ugly way to do that.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it's hard to say.  I suspect you probably need more logic in your model rather than writing binding handlers etc

Comment: Uh yeah I think you're really over complicating it.  I may have time for a detailed answer later, but in short: the final 3 images should probably be generated from values in an `observableArray` and use the `click` binding to run a function on your viewmodel that updates an observable that's used as the `src` (via the `attr` binding) on the first image.

Comment: I have like 20 properties inside item observable. So I really need the property name to change the value of that observable not the attribute. Thats why I have my update function in my item bindinghandler. If I just change the src attribute the value of observable doesn't change. Because I need to return back the updated item observable in my api

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ahead of yourself with the custom binding.

The bottom line is: You don't need a custom binding for what you want to do. It's easy - if you don't make it complicated:

```js
function loadImages() {
    // return $.get(url);
    
    // mockup Ajax response, in place of a real $.get call
    return $.Deferred().resolve({
        items: [
            {height: 20, width: 20, src: 'http://placehold.it/150/30ac17', title: 'image 1'},
            {height: 20, width: 20, src: 'http://placehold.it/150/412ffd', title: 'image 2'},
            {height: 20, width: 20, src: 'http://placehold.it/150/c672a0', title: 'image 3'}
        ]
    }).promise();
}

function ImageList() {
    var self = this;
    
    // data
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    
    // init
    loadImages().done(function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ImageList())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
  <img data-bind="attr: {height: 25, width: 25, src: src}">
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <img data-bind="attr: {height: height, width: width, src: src}, click: $root.selectedItem" />
</div>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Note how I use `selectedItem` as a click event handler. This is possible because in event handlers, knockout passes the relevant object (in this case, an image object from the array) as the first argument. Conveniently, observables set their value to the first argument you call them with. And presto: You have click event handler that sets the last clicked object.

---

**EDIT**

> "I need multiple selected item then my items are just my context menu not just one selected item."

```js
function loadImages() {
    // return $.get(url);
    
    // mockup Ajax response, in place of a real $.get call
    return $.Deferred().resolve({
        items: [
            {height: 20, width: 20, src: 'http://placehold.it/150/30ac17', title: 'image 1'},
            {height: 20, width: 20, src: 'http://placehold.it/150/412ffd', title: 'image 2'},
            {height: 20, width: 20, src: 'http://placehold.it/150/c672a0', title: 'image 3'}
        ]
    }).promise();
}

function ImageList() {
    var self = this;
    
    // data
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();
    
    // init
    loadImages().done(function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    });

    self.selectItem = function (item) {
        var pos = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.selectedItems(), item);
        if (pos === -1) self.selectedItems.push(item);
    };
    self.deselectItem = function (item) {
        var pos = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.selectedItems(), item);
        if (pos !== -1) self.selectedItems.remove(item);
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ImageList())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
  <img data-bind="attr: {height: 25, width: 25, src: src}, click: $root.deselectItem">
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <img data-bind="attr: {height: height, width: width, src: src}, click: $root.selectItem" />
</div>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: oooh nice trick with the `click` handler to the `observable`.  Not seen that before.

Comment: As I said item observable isn't observable array. It has properties in it that isn't a collection

Comment: For example it has { img1: 'path', img2: 'path', img3: 'path' }

Comment: That's the properties I need to return

Comment: @dan That data model does not make any sense. You are trying to use an object like an array and then you wonder that it doesn't work very well. It's way easier to change your data model into something sensible than trying to make knockout work against its design.

Comment: I need multiple selected item then my items are just my context menu not just one selected item.

Comment: Well, have an observable array of selected items, then. I still don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div  data-bind="foreach: {data: skills, as: 'skill'}" >
    <div data-bind="foreach: Object.keys(skill)" >
        <a data-bind="text: $data"></a> :   <a data-bind="text: skill[$data]"></a>
    </div>    
</div>


v = new function AppViewModel() {
    this.skills = [{rates:"sdfdcvxcsd", cat: 2, car:55}, {color:"sdfdcvxcsd", zoo: 2,boat:55}];
}

ko.applyBindings(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**view:**

```
<div data-bind="test:name,propertyName:'name'"></div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var propertyName = allBindings().propertyName; //property name here
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, valueAccessor);
        alert(propertyName)
    }
};

function Employee() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("John");
}

ko.applyBindings(new Employee());
```

working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tg/985/)**

Comment: I want to return "name" not the "John".

Comment: What's in my head now is to get the value of attribute data-bind using jquery so my return would be "test: name". But is there other way to do that?

Comment: well i believe there is no documented way to read a observable property name inside binding handlers but u can try passing property name static(ugly way) and read it inside binding handlers

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the observable name.

This converts the `valueAccessor` (`function(){return name }`) to a string which is then split to remove the observable `name`.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.GetObservableName = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observableName = String(valueAccessor).split(' ')[1];
        alert(observableName);
    }
};

function Employee() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("John");
}

<div data-bind="GetObservableName: name"></div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tg/986/)

The index of the `split` method in the fiddle is different to the one in the example above. The above works for me in Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks